# Pandas - Fill the blank column with some value

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am looking to create a new column 'isRunning' in the data frame by identifying the 'Task' column status. Also, I have a 'Session' column and if a Session only has START value in the Task and no END vaule (for example, Session 3 has only START val), so 'isRunning' should have TRUE flag untill the end of that session.

|  | Session | Task | isRunning |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 1 | START | TRUE |
| 1 | 1 |  | TRUE |
| 2 | 1 |  | TRUE |
| 3 | 1 |  | TRUE |
| 4 | 1 | END | TRUE |
| 5 | 1 |  | FALSE |
| 6 | 2 |  | FALSE |
| 7 | 2 | START | TRUE |
| 8 | 2 |  | TRUE |
| 9 | 2 | END | TRUE |
| 10 | 2 |  | FALSE |
| 11 | 2 |  | FALSE |
| 12 | 3 |  | FALSE |
| 13 | 3 | START | TRUE |
| 14 | 3 |  | TRUE |
| 15 | 3 |  | TRUE |
| 16 | 4 |  | FALSE |
| 17 | 4 | START | TRUE |
| 18 | 4 |  | TRUE |
| 19 | 4 |  | TRUE |
| 20 | 4 | END | TRUE |

Not sure how to move forward with adding an extra condition and identifying if the Task is running.

```py
import pandas as pd
d = {'Session':[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4],
         'Task':['START', '', '', '', 'END', '', '', 'START', '', 'END', '', '', '', 'START', '', '', '', 'START', '', '', 'END']}

df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
```

Comment: Please provide the code you've tried

Comment: Can a session have multiple starts and ends?

Comment: Yes, the sessions can have multiple starts and ends.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming one start/end per group. You can use a double mask:

```
m1 = df['Task'].eq('START').groupby(df['Session]').cummax()

m2 = df.loc[::-1, 'Task'].eq('END').groupby(df['Session']).cummax()

df['IsRunning'] = m1&m2
```

If several start/end per session are possible:

```
df['IsRunning'] = (df['Task'].map({'START': True, 'END': False})
                   .groupby(df['Session']).ffill()
                   .fillna(False)
                ) | df['Task'].eq('END')
```

Output:

```
    Session   Task  IsRunning
0         1  START       True
1         1              True
2         1              True
3         1              True
4         1    END       True
5         1             False
6         2             False
7         2  START       True
8         2              True
9         2    END       True
10        2             False
11        2             False
12        3             False
13        3  START       True
14        3              True
15        3              True
16        4             False
17        4  START       True
18        4              True
19        4              True
20        4    END       True
```

Comment: one session can have multiple starts and stops

Comment: @ImSean007 see update. Can you please provide the DataFrame constructor of your input?

Comment: I have the above-provided table in a csv file, which I am directly loading into my DataFrame. It only has two columns 'Task' and 'Session'.
Also, I have tried your code and it is able to mark the Is Running status, except for the row with 'END' as Task value value

Comment: @ImSean007 check that you copied the whole code, including `| df['Task'].eq('END')`. I added the output for clarity.

Comment: @ mozway thanks op, I missed the OR condition initially